# Automatic checkout after push

Tags: git, githooks

I have a server on which I send the results of my work. After each command `git push` I have to connect via SSH and enter the command to switch my remote repository to the latest version:

```
git checkout NNNN
```

Can I simplify this action?

P.S. Before submitting of this question I had found some information about GitHooks. Can I use it for my task described above and, for example for restarting Rails server after checkout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can simplify it!

Suppose, you are using Github. Create a webservice, accessible from the web with the language of your choice. The service will need to accept [requests like this](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks#the-payload) and do the work you need. After it is created go Github. In your project's settings go to `Settings` and then to `Service Hooks`. You'll need to add `WebHook URL`. Enter the URL of your service. That's all. Bitbucket also has such feature, named `Service` in admin area of your project. You need to create `POST` service to do this.

If you host your repo on your own server, you can use [`post-update` hook](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html).

There is no `post-push` hooks, or something similar to it, so you cannot simply trigger jobs on your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Before first commit into remote repo to avoid `error: refusing to update` I forced to do:

```
git config receive.denycurrentbranch ignore
```

To enable auto checkout it is enought to set

```
git config receive.denycurrentbranch updateInstead
```